# Одинаковые имена полей с разным типом в JSON

Tags: java, android, json, rest

К примеру, есть модели:

```
public class Shipment {
     private int id;
     private Destination destination
     private String status;
}

public class Destination {
     private int id;
     private String company;
     private String nameTo;
}

public class Order {
     private int id;
     private String reference;
     private List<Shipment> shipments;
}
```

Есть `JSON` ответ чтобы получить `Order`:

```
{
    "id": 78,
    "reference": "FD456",
    "shipments": [
                  {
                    "id": 86160,
                    "destination": 172002,
                    "status": "ready"
                  }
}
```

Есть `JSON` ответ чтобы получить `Shipment`:

```
{
    "id": 86160,
    "destination": [
                  {
                    "id": 172002,
                    "company": "KLM inc",
                    "name_to": "Alex"
                  }
    "status": "ready"
}
```

Как видно в первом `JSON` поле `destination` хранит просто `id`, а во втором `JSON` приходит уже сам объект `Destination`. Как я понимаю это сделано в целях оптимизации, но вопрос состоит в том, как хранить такое различие типов в моделях?

Comment: Честно говоря, есть вопросы к содержимому JSON. Я бы не стал передавать в списке моделей Shipments, который находится в модели Order что-то, кроме их id.

Comment: Как мне кажется, такое сделано с целью уменьшения траффика. Зачем передавать один и тот же объект в двух запросах? Достаточно id, по которому можно будет его дергать.

Comment: Json для Shipment имеет неправильную структуру. "destination" - это все таки массив или объект?

Comment: Для Shipment правильно json указан? В объекте не вижу массивов или листов...

Comment: Ну, а вообще логично было бы для двух разных моделей json'а использовать две разных моделей pojo... Во многих библиотеках можно для полей объекта (да и для самого объекта) указать имя в json-представлении. Лично мне понравилась библиотека jackson, у неё вполне удобный маршаллинг, к тому же, она универсальна, маршаллирует еще и xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Такое получилось из-за БД на стороне API

С точки зрения API там два разных типа данных: сама модель и **ссылка** на модель. *В самом общем смысле.* "Голый id" это **ссылка**, по которой API может однозначно найти нужную запись. *Скорее всего, это внешний ключ в какой-то SQL-базе.*

Если у вас, потребителя API, есть своя БД, то в ней это можно представить, как поле, хранящее ..._api_id (где ссылка) и api_id (где значение). Как внешний и первичный ключ (соотв-но), но поскольку в базе "снаружи", соответствующие значения есть не всегда. Если пришла ссылка, то сохранить только в это поле, если значение, то сделать строчку в другой таблице **и** заполнить это поле.

А если базы нет, можно завести singleton-мапы `id => объект` и... дальше варианты.

- Если вы уверены, что эти объекты меняются редко, эти мапы можно использовать, как кэш. Например, получили вы `id`, и оказалось, что в мапе эта запись уже есть (ранее у API спрашивалась), можно её сразу и взять.
- А если считаете, что они меняются часто, то вам придётся делать ещё один запрос, чтобы точно получить самую свежую версию объекта.
- Можно совместить два подхода, и обновлять объект только если запрос был достаточно давно. Да-да, пресловутый "cache invalidation".

Так или иначе, в объекте у вас будет только число — ключ для мапа. Если в мапе такого значения нет, его надо достать с API и записать в мап. Вам стоит поискать в этом API место, которое вам этот объект выдаст целиком.

В приведённых JSON-ответах разработчики, вероятно, решили, что данные смежных объектов нужны часто и решили их вложить по значению, а не по ссылке.

Answer (score 4):

Так а в чём сложность то? Проверяйте при сериализации/десериализации в json какие данные есть и в зависимости от этого или создавайте/меняйте destination, или просто прогружайте по id. Конфликта то с конечной моделью, в которой идёт ссылка на объёкт, а не его id то нету.

Answer (score 4):

Не суть важно в чем причина такого ответа JSON от сервера. Я так понимаю ТС не контролирует что ему выдает сервер - иначе он бы изменил JSON ответ :)

Теперь к сути вопроса: суть если кратко состоит в том, что объект `Destination` сериализуется иногда как полномасштабный объект, а иногда только как `id` - вопрос - как обрабатывать это на этапе десериализации (посколько сериализацию мы не контролируем, то остается только этап десериализации).

**Ответ:**

Модель оставляем такой как описано у вас. Далее берем [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) и пишем десериализатор, примерно так:

```
public class MyDeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject object = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        if (object.has("destination")) 
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement, Destination.class);
        else 
            return context.deserialize(jsonElement, typeOfT);
    }
}
```

Такой десериализатор, всегда будет заставлять парсить поле `destination` как объект `Destination`

Финальный штрих - встраивание десериализатора в парсер:

```
GSon gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new MyDeSerializer())
            .create();
```

P.S. Писал на коленках, так что не взыщите. Здесь изложена только идея, остальное уже сами.

Answer (score 2):

Объекты различные - модели будут разные в соответствии с разной структурой объектов. Не стоит делать общую универсальную модель.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, является - предлагается сделать 2 разных класса.